# how to create a new folder using alfresco api

Tags: alfresco

I have uploaded sample.zip file in this directory CompanyHome/site/testsite/documentlibrary/test.

Now I want to create new folder called childfolder under above directory [CompanyHome/site/testsite/documentlibrary/test/childfolder] and move the sample.zip under it.using Alfresco API how do i create child folder and move the file under newly created childfolder?

Comment: Are you trying to do this every time a file is added to the test folder by anyone? Or do you need to do this from the command-line or some other system?

Comment: yes.users are going to upload zip files.

Comment: when user upload a zip file in this path CompanyHome/site/testsite/documentlibrary/test then subfolder should be created and move this zip file to that subfolder.

Answer (score 4):

This really depends upon what version of Alfresco you're using and what API you want to use to do it. For example, assuming that you want to do this via a REST API then you have the option of [CMIS](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/pra/1/topics/cmis-welcome.html), the recent "[Public API](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/pra/1/concepts/pra-resources.html)" or the internal [WebScript](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts) based API.

Alternatively, you might want to do this by using the [JavaScript API](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/JavaScript_API_Cookbook) and WebScript develop your own WebScripts.

There are lots of ways to achieve this - perhaps you can provide some more information on the overall picture of what you're trying to do and where you're trying to do this (e.g. as an extension of Share maybe?).

It's possible to create a folder within Share and if you do so whilst you have browser developer tools open you'll be able to see the exact REST API calls that are used.

Comment: we are using 4.2 version